# Comparision between MPI standard and Map-Reduce programming model?

Tags: mapreduce, cloud, mpi, distributed-computing

As i have learned basics of various parallel paradigm standard such as OpenMP, MPI, OpenCL to write parallel programming. But i don't have much knowledge about Map-Reduce Programming model.

As it is well known that various popular companies are following the Map-Reduce programming model to solve their huge data intensive tasks. As well as MPI was designed for high performance computing on both massively parallel machines and on workstation clusters.

So my first confusion is ..
Can i use the Map-Reduce model instead of MPI standard or vice-versa?  or it depends upon the applications!!

What is the exact difference between them?

```
Which one is better and when?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could understand Map-Reduce as a subset of MPI-functionality, as it kind of resembles MPIs collective operations with user-defined functions. Thus you can use MPI instead of Map-Reduce but not vice-versa, as in MPI you can describe many more operations. The main advantage of Map-Reduce seems to be this concentration on this single parallel concept, thereby reducing interfaces that you need to learn in order to use it.

Comment: it is really gud one...Now assume we have a problem which requires only collective operations then in this case which one will be the better option to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, have a look at: http://www.unixer.de/publications/img/hoefler-map-reduce-mpi.pdf they describe how to implement map-reduce ontop of MPI to make it faster. Thus the conclusion is probably if you want speed you are better off with MPI. Otherwise you have define your criteria for better more specifically.